# Running a seasonal decomposition on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, stl

I am learning to code in R and have been strugling to get something very simple to work. I have a database with prices of products, each column represents the time series of a product. I want to run a Seasonal Decomposition of Time Series on each column and get the results in a list separated by product name.

When I run the code below I get the error:

Error in assign(paste(j), x[j]) <- (stl(dados_resumo[, x], s.window = "periodic")) :   could not find function "assign<-"

```
for (i in 1:3)
{
    x <- (i)
    for(j in colnames(df)){
    assign(paste(j), x[j]) <- (stl(df[,x], s.window="periodic"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data frame looks like, so I'll have a go at this manually.

Firstly, assign isn't a function, which is exactly what the error is telling you.

```
for( i in 1:length( df ) )
{
   df$stl[i] <- stl( df[,i], s.window = "periodic" )
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but now I get a new error: 


Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable


Maybe the error is related to my data frame?

A sample of my data frame:


             Coentro Rucula TomateComum
    Jan 2007   10.44   7.39        3.30
    Feb 2007    5.75   6.32        3.40
    Mar 2007    6.52   5.86        4.56
    Apr 2007   13.90   6.00        3.06
    May 2007   12.25   5.44        2.14
    Jun 2007    7.37   5.22        2.34

Comment: It's a bit hard to see without the DF itself, run a google search on the error and a couple of SO answers will appear which will show you. In R, a function is also known as a closure, which is where your issue lies. I'll hazard a guess you've named a variable (perhaps your data frame), the name of something that is also a function, eg data.

Answer (score 0):

'assign<-' is not a function, however, 'assign' is;
which is used in the form of assign(varname,varvalue,environment)
for example, if you want to assign value "bigworld" to varible named x in global environment
you can use

```
assign(x,"bigworld",envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

envir can be set as envir = .GlobalEnv so that even in a function deep in stack or calling chain, you can assign value to var in global environment

the equation

```
 x = a
```

or

```
 x <- a
```

can also be used for assigning but inside the function, this will not affect the value globally, once the function is returned, x is removed